# Override css hover so that it does nothing AT ALL

Tags: css, wordpress, hover, media-queries

Specifically, I am working on a child theme of twentytwelve in Wordpress.

What I am trying to do is change the width to a larger screen size for the mobile menu.

The problem I am having is overriding hover so that it does nothing.

twentytwelve has:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 600px){

        .main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }
}
```

I want the mobile menu on the ipad so I tried:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

        .main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
            display: none;
        }
}
```

Sure that overrides it but does too much. What if .main-navigation ul li ul is visible.  When .main-navigation ul li:hover it disappears.

I need it to actually do NOTHING, not hide it...

Comment: Try `(min-width: 1024px)` for the first code

Comment: why don't you just remove `display: none;` from media-query...???so it would do nothing as you want

Comment: @SurjithSM The first code is in the twentytwelve theme.  That's the whole point of a child theme: not to edit the main theme to not lose changes in updates.

Comment: @NoobEditor Then that won't override anything.  I still need it to not display because of hover.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your second media query will be triggered only when the screen reach a width between **601** and **767** pixels.

Secondly, if you want to establish prior for one of those media queries, you can use the `!important` declaration – I can say that is a common practice of mine. [Learn more.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)

---

*Edited based on commentaries.*

Try the following:

```
@media screen (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 768px){
    .main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: First: That's the point.  The hover is not implemented in twentytwelve below 600px.  I want to move it up to 768px. That's why  I put max-width:768px  I only need it to be triggered between those two numbers.

Comment: Second: Sure, I got it to work using !important when I want to display it, keeping the above code the same.  But I don't like using !important if I don't have to.  It defeats the whole cascading idea.

Comment: Actually the `!important` declaration is here for that, Joshua. Your problem is logical. By the way, I've updated my answer, take a look.